# Proving summation terminates only when denominator is of form 2^p *5^q and the expansion being unique

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a positive rational $a$, we can take $w$ as its integral part $[x]$ and $y$ as fractional part $\{x\}$

Show that the fractional part can be expressed as the below summation.
$$
y=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{y_{k}}{10^{k}}
$$
where $y_{k}$ are integers satisfying
$$
0 \leq y_{k} \leq 9
$$
for $k=1,2, \ldots .$ Here the sum can be infinite. (If $y$ is rational then it can be shown that the series is finite if and only if the denominator of $y$ (in its reduced form) has no prime factors other than 2 and 5 .

> I tried to show that a fractional part can be expressed in that way by arguing that we have masses of 1/10,1/100 etc and they are avaiable atmost 9 pieces of each type, its possible to put those in a way so as to get a propery balance from the other side which has y mass . But how do we able to show that the series terminates if and only if denominator of y is of form $2^p * 5^q$ ? And is there a way we can show that this expansion is unique ? There cannot be any other expansion from that summatiom which gives same y?

Comment: With uniqueness do you mean the uniqueness of the decimal expansion or the uniqueness of the representation as a fraction in lowest terms ?

Comment: If the decimal expansion of $a$ terminates, then there is a positive integer $k$ , such that $10^k\cdot a$ is an integer. The denominator of the fraction in lowest terms must therefore be a divisor of a power of $10$ , hence cannot have a prime factor different from $2$ and $5$.

Comment: $y_k=\begin{cases}2&\text{if }k=1\\9&\text{if }k>1\end{cases}$ and $y_k=\begin{cases}3&\text{if }k=1\\0&\text{if }k>1\end{cases}$ are two distinct expansions of the same number $\frac 3{10}$.

Comment: @Peter thanks i got the terminate part now .  And by uniquencess yeah i mean as expansion term , is it not unique there ?

Comment: Okay fine @HagenvonEitzen then its just the uniqueness is based on representing as a rational number only right ? Nothing else?

Comment: The decimal expansion is always unique , if we omit the artifical period $\bar 9$ (every such number has also a terminating expansion). Since you demand the expansion to terminate anyway, there is no problem with the non-uniqueness.

Comment: Irrational numbers and rational numbers with a denominator having some prime factor different from $2$ and $5$ in the lowest terms have a unique representation. Only the terminating case has a collision with the $9$-period. There is no other occurence of non-uniqueness.